React does not recognize the `initialValues` prop on a DOM element
react does not recognize the initialValues prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase initialvalues instead....
I know the cause and the solution, but I want to change the solution to the minimum, such as how to turn off this warning, because I made my own component library, external props are not controllable, I can not filter one by one.

Not really a lot you can do, bar forking the libraries to fix them or going the nuclear option and disabling console output. Edit: wait, you say this is a custom library you wrote? In that case, fix the problem.

Yes, I double-encapsulated, I mapped the components, so some components needed props that others might not, and even some of the low code passed props, so controlling the props was a bit of a hassle.
